# How to handle JSOUP (version 1.12.1) exception java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL

Tags: java, jsoup

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String jsonURL = "http://jpmc.fa.oraclecloud.com/hcmRestApi/resources/latest/recruitingCEJobRequisitions?onlyData=true&expand=requisitionList.secondaryLocations&finder=findReqs;siteNumber=CX_1002,facetsList=LOCATIONS%3BWORK_LOCATIONS%3BTITLES%3BCATEGORIES%3BPOSTING_DATES,limit=24,locationId=300000000289738,offset=24";
            Response res = Jsoup.connect(jsonURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36").ignoreContentType(true).maxBodySize(0).timeout(0).execute();

            String resBody = res.body();
            System.out.println(resBody);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I got response of same Url in JSoup 1.7 but as I Updated JSoup version to 1.12 same Url response shows me

> java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL

please tell me how to handle this or any other way to get response of this url.

Comment: Issue resolved. I handled this url in HTTPUrlConnection.
I got this URL response in HTTPUrlConncetion by adding followredirects(true).

Comment: That's great! You can post as an answer below, self-answered questions are encouraged. You can even accept your own answer!